# SVG - linearGradient - stop offset/stop-color attribute Angular

Tags: angular, svg

I have an SVG rectangle which needs to be filled dynamically based on the value in object.

Issue :: all my rect elements are filled with same color code (stop-color) and same percentage (offset) as per the first iteration value, remaining iteration values are not applied.

```
<div class="col col-sm-3" *ngFor="let box of boxes; let i = index;">
<svg width="240" height="140" id="svg2" version="1.1" viewBox="60 -40 180 220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs> 
<linearGradient id="MyGradient" x2="0%" y1="1" x1 ="0" y2="0">
<stop attr.offset="{{ box[i].fper }}%" [attr.stop-color]="box.color"></stop>
<stop attr.offset="{{ box[i].fper }}%" stop-color="#FFFFFF"></stop>        
<stop attr.offset="{{ box[i].eper }}%" stop-color="#FFFFFF"></stop>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<rect fill="url(#MyGradient)" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" x="15" y="8" width="300" height="145">
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: how many elements with id="MyGradient" are on the page. If > 1 then the page is invalid.

Comment: Yes thatnks Robert Longson - changed the id as attr.id="MyGradient{{i}}" and now working. Thanks a lot for your input.